How do I make the Matrox Model Finder look for the same model multiple times in a single image?
I'm new to Matrox so this might be a very beginner question.
I have a pallet with multiple items that are all the same model. When I add the ModelFinder step to the program, I add the model I'm looking for, but it only shows me the one I registered, I'm guessing because of the distortion of the camera. How do I get Matrox to know that there are more items and that they're also the same model?

I added a search region where it has to be found, and I selected the option for it to find all occurrences, but it's only showing me one instead of the 3/4 that are actually there.

